# Графы, их применение и недостатки

Tags: графы

Подскажите пожалуйста какова область применения графов?

Какие в основном решаются задачи на графах?

Какие задачи труднорешаемы на графах? И вообще для чего графы не подходят?
Просто я начал про них читать, получается, что с помощью графов можно описать все что угодно, вот хотелось бы узнать их недостатки.

Answer (score 4):

Применение теории графов есть практически в любой дисциплине и, конечно же, в программировании - с помощью теории графов реализуется множество алгоритмов, связанных с деревьями, о чем можно почитать, скажем в [этой](http://www.rsdn.ru/res/book/prog/basic_algorithms.xml) замечательной книге. Если говорить о самом что ни есть прикладном применении, то теория графов применяется , например,в логистике (при расчете всяческих маршрутов), в электротехнике (при моделировании электрических цепей) и даже в [Компьютерной химии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%8F)

К недостаткам можно отнести некоторую прожорливость в плане памяти, пропорциональную числу вершин графа, что вполне логично

Comment: @DreamChild 

    прожорливость в плане памяти, пропорциональную числу вершин графа

это вопросы реализации. Матрица смежности, например имеет размерность n^2

Answer (score 4):

Наверно графы все таки инструмент для решения задач, поэтому недостатки появляются только при неправильном применении. Так, например, молотком сложно подстричь ногти и это недостаток, но не молотка, а метода его применения в контексте данной задачи.

Ну и отсюда следует что графы не подходят для тех задач, которые к алгоритмам из теории графов не сводятся.

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с аналогией про молоток. Графами можно сделать почти всё, но далеко не всегда это будет оптимально. И, наверное, надо ещё сказать, что это всё-таки не структура(т.к. представлений графов полно), а математическая абстракция.
Т.е. массив можно рассматривать как бинарное дерево, но вы ведь не будете говорить про список, что это граф!
Наверное большинство задач на графах -- поиск пути:). В частности, логистика.